# format string with comma

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting a string output as : `A B C D`

I want to get it converted to: `A,B,C and D`.

Is there and function in PostgreSQL to do it.

Comment: Have you tried something? At least, something like `REPLACE(' ', ',')` to begin with?

Comment: What is the query that produced that result? You ask if there a function to do that. Well YES- there are several. Your query may need nothing be a simple function change, but there is no way to determine that. **Always** when showing query results include the query.

Comment: Yes @Andrew i replaced the space with comma. but what to do with last comma and there many be n number of strings. how to identify the last comma and replace the same with AND.

Comment: @Belayer consider it to be the concatenation of multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select REPLACE('A B C D', ' ', ',')
```

And to replace `A,B,C,D` to `A,B,C and D` use the following:

```
select substring('A,B,C,D',1,
length('A,B,C,D')-position(',' in reverse('A,B,C,D'))) 
 || ' and ' || 
substring('A,B,C,D',length('A,B,C,D')-position(',' in reverse('A,B,C,D'))+2);
```

You can combine the above with `replace` to make it single query.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a two-step approach. The first step replaces all spaces with a comma. And then the last comma is replaced with the AND using a regular expression:

```
regexp_replace(replace('A B C D',' ',','), '(.*)(,)(\w+)$', '\1 and \3')
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=01ab38eb59baa09e4c792ee9d74ec25b)

Answer (score 0):

No need to complicate things.
A single regex function that capture each element and lets you do whatever you want with it.

```
select regexp_replace(mycol, '(\S)+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S)\s+(\S+)','\1,\2,\3 and \4')
from   mytab
```

-

```
+----------------+
| regexp_replace |
+----------------+
| A,B,C and D    |
+----------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b733c/3/0)

Comment: I think the number of strings is not constant.